# Wix Bundle Managed Bootstrapper Application - Error 0x80131524: Failed to create the bootstrapper application

Tags: c#, bootstrapper, wix4

I want to create a custom installer with Managed Bootstrapper Application in WiX toolset v4. The tutorial what I used to setup a simple example installer was this: https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/grow-from-a-newbie-to-pro-in-creating-the-installers.aspx#creating-a-custom-ui-installer
However, on the v3 of the WiX toolset everything works fine. I tried to adapt the described projects to run on WiX toolset v4.

When running the installer, the log shows this error messages:

```
[3264:2A08][2023-07-21T11:57:09]i000: Loading managed bootstrapper application.
[3264:2A08][2023-07-21T11:57:09]e000: Error 0x80131524: Failed to create the bootstrapper application.
[3264:2A08][2023-07-21T11:57:09]e000: Error 0x80131524: Failed to create the managed bootstrapper application.
[3264:2A08][2023-07-21T11:57:09]e000: Error 0x80131524: Failed to create BA.
[3264:2A08][2023-07-21T11:57:09]e000: Error 0x80131524: Failed to load BA.
[3264:2A08][2023-07-21T11:57:09]e000: Error 0x80131524: Failed while running 
[3264:2A08][2023-07-21T11:57:09]i502: Cleanup begin.
```

What did I adapt?
In Project CustomBootstrapperApplication:
using WixToolset.Mba.Core instead of Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper

add CustomUI.Factory.cs

```
[assembly: WixToolset.Mba.Core.BootstrapperApplicationFactory(typeof(CustomBootstrapperApplication.CustomUIFactory))]
namespace CustomBootstrapperApplication
{
    using WixToolset.Mba.Core;

    public class CustomUIFactory : BaseBootstrapperApplicationFactory
    {
        protected override IBootstrapperApplication Create(IEngine engine, IBootstrapperCommand command)
        {
            return new CustomUI(engine);
        }
    }
}
```

In CustomUI.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using WixToolset.Mba.Core;

namespace CustomBootstrapperApplication
{
    public class CustomUI : BootstrapperApplication
    {
        public CustomUI(IEngine engine) : base(engine)
        {
        }

        public IEngine Engine => this.engine;

        public static Dispatcher BootstrapperDispatcher { get; private set; }

        // public static MainWindow view;

        protected override void Run()
        {
            this.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Launching Custom UI");
            BootstrapperDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

            MainWindow view = new MainWindow(this);
            view.Bootstrapper.Engine.Detect();
            view.DataContext = view;
            view.Closed += (sender, e) => BootstrapperDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
            view.Show();

            Dispatcher.Run();
            this.Engine.Quit(0);
        }

    }
}
```

rename CustomUI.cs to WixToolset.Mba.Host.config and adapt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="wix.bootstrapper" type="WixToolset.Mba.Host.BootstrapperSectionGroup, WixToolset.Mba.Host">
      <section name="host" type="WixToolset.Mba.Host.HostSection, WixToolset.Mba.Host" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
  </startup>
  <wix.bootstrapper>
    <host assemblyName="CustomBootstrapperApplication">
    </host>
  </wix.bootstrapper>
</configuration>
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs using type CustomUI instead of BootstrapperApplication

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using WixToolset.Mba.Core;

namespace CustomBootstrapperApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private bool isInstall;
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainView class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainWindow(CustomUI bootstrapper)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Bootstrapper = bootstrapper;
            this.Bootstrapper.DetectPackageComplete += this.OnDetectPackageComplete;
            this.Bootstrapper.PlanComplete += this.OnPlanComplete;
            this.Bootstrapper.ExecuteProgress += this.OnExecuteProgress;
            this.Bootstrapper.ExecuteComplete += this.OnExecuteComplete;
            this.Bootstrapper.ExecuteBegin += this.OnExecuteBegin;
        }
        public CustomUI Bootstrapper { get; private set; }

        private void Exit_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CustomUI.BootstrapperDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        }

        private void Install_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            isInstall = true;
            Install_Button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            process.Content = "Waiting to Install...";
            Bootstrapper.Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Install);
        }

        private void Uninstall_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            isInstall = false;
            Uninstall_Button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            process.Content = "Waiting to Uninstall...";
            Bootstrapper.Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Uninstall);
        }

        private void OnExecuteComplete(object sender, ExecuteCompleteEventArgs e)
        {

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(
                      delegate ()
                      {
                          if (isInstall)
                          {
                              process.Content = "Installed";
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              process.Content = "Uninstalled";
                          }
                      }));

        }
        private void OnExecuteBegin(object sender, ExecuteBeginEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(
                      delegate ()
                      {
                          if (isInstall)
                          {
                              process.Content = "Installing...";
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              process.Content = "Uninstalling...";
                          }
                      }));
        }

        private void OnDetectPackageComplete(object sender, DetectPackageCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(
                      delegate ()
                      {
                          if (e.PackageId == "Sample")
                          {
                              if (e.State == PackageState.Absent)
                              {
                                  Install_Button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                                  Uninstall_Button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                              }

                              else if (e.State == PackageState.Present)
                              {
                                  Uninstall_Button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                                  Install_Button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

                              }
                          }
                      }));
        }

        private void OnPlanComplete(object sender, PlanCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Status >= 0)
                Bootstrapper.Engine.Apply(System.IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        private void OnExecuteProgress(object sender, ExecuteProgressEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(
                      delegate ()
                      {
                          progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
                      }));
        }
    }
}
```

Created a new "Bundle (WiX v4)" Project BootstrapperDefaultUI:

adapt the Bundle.wxs

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal">
  <Bundle Name="BootstrapperDefaultUI" Manufacturer="TODO Manufacturer" Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="7ee73ecd-5bb0-47e1-9e9b-25883e076b17">
    <BootstrapperApplication>

      
      <Payload SourceFile="..\CustomBootstrapperApplication\bin\Debug\CustomBootstrapperApplication.dll" />
      <Payload SourceFile="..\CustomBootstrapperApplication\bin\Debug\CustomBootstrapperApplication.dll.config" />
      <Payload SourceFile="..\CustomBootstrapperApplication\bin\Debug\CustomBootstrapperApplication.pdb" />
      <Payload SourceFile="..\CustomBootstrapperApplication\bin\Debug\WixToolset.Mba.Core.dll" />
      <Payload SourceFile="..\CustomBootstrapperApplication\bin\Debug\WixToolset.Mba.Core.xml" />
      <Payload SourceFile="..\CustomBootstrapperApplication\bin\Debug\WixToolset.Mba.Host.config" />

      <bal:WixManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost />
      
    </BootstrapperApplication>

    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\SampleWixApplication\bin\x86\Debug\en-US\SampleWixApplication.msi" bal:PrereqPackage="yes" />
    </Chain>

  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dllnotfoundexception?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 1):

Add **`<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>`** to CustomBootstrapperApplication project this will output another dll into your output folder called **mbanative.dll**.

Add **mbanative.dll** as PayLoad into your BootstrapperApplication, similar to what you did to the other dlls.